# Preserving symmetry while sculpting

Tags: sculpting, sculpt-mode

Whenever I try to edit a model in sculpt mode, the symmetry is messed up. The model is perfectly symmetrical before hand, but after sculpting (even when using the x-mirror), the symmetry is gone. Is there a setting that preserves the symmetry?

Comment: Make sure that the rotation is applied (Ctrl A in Object mode), and that the origin is at the center (right click >Set Origin > Origin to Geometry), the symmetry should work, or please share your object so that we can give a try